# javascript extract numbers from string not working

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a sample `str1` `"14 girls"` 
`str2` `"178 guys"`

i tried the following in chrome console to extract the numbers 12 and 178, could anyone please tell me what went wrong?

```
str.match(/^\d{2}$/)  to get the number of girls i.e. `14`

str.match(/^[0-9]{2}?$/)
```

What would be an easy way to get the numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's guaranteed that the numbers will always be at the start of the string, just use:

```
var n = parseInt(s, 10);
```

The [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function will stop parsing at the first non-numeric character.

The reason your regular expressions didn't work is because you finished them with `$` - meaning that they would only match if the *entire* string was a two digit number.

Answer (score 0):

i think will be better:

```
str.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g)
```

This will give you an array of all numbers with float in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
var pattern=/[0-9]+/;
```

so...

```
var str='123abc';
//var str='abc123';
document.write(str.match(pattern));
```